# Execute parent function from jquery mobile dialog window

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

Is there anyway to execute parent functions and affect parent variables from inside a jquery mobile dialog window?

[EDITED TO ADD CODE]

On the parent the user taps on the link for the dialog which is:

```
<a href="options-window.php" data-rel="dialog" id="dlg-options-window"></a>
```

And then is brought to the dialog which like so (sliderOneVal and sliderTwoVal are variables created and populated by the parent):

```
<div id="option-window" data-role="page">
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#layer-window').on('dialogcreate', function( event, ui ){
    $('#sliderOne').val(sliderOneVal);
    $('#sliderTwoOption').val(sliderTwoVal);    

    $('.sliderSelector').bind('change', sliderClicked() );    

});
</script>
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="d"><h5>Options</h5></div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical" data-role="fieldcontain"><table>
            <tr>
                <td><select name="sliderOne" id="sliderOne" class="sliderSelector" data-theme="" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
                    <option value="off">Off</option>
                    <option value="on">On</option>
                </select></td>
                <td><label for="sliderOne">Option One</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><select name="sliderTwo" id="sliderTwo" class="sliderSelector" data-theme="" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
                    <option value="off">Off</option>
                    <option value="on">On</option>
                </select></td>
                <td><label for="sliderTwo">Option Two</label></td>
            </tr>
            </table></fieldset>
        </div>
</div>
```

And here is sliderClicked() which is in the parent document it gets which of the sliders was clicked and its current value, then changes the values of the appropriate variable accordingly:

```
function sliderClicked(){
    sliderVal = $(this).val();
    sliderID = $(this).attr("id");


    if(sliderVal=="on" && sliderID=="sliderOne"){
        sliderOneVal="on";
    } else if(sliderVal=="off" && sliderID=="sliderOne"){
        sliderOneVal="off";
    }

    if(sliderVal=="on" && sliderID=="sliderTwo") {
        sliderTwoVal="on";
    } else if(sliderVal=="off" && sliderID=="sliderTwo"){
        sliderTwoVal="off";
    }
    console.log('sliderOneVal:'+sliderOneVal);
    console.log('sliderTwoVal:'+sliderTwoVal);
}
```

Comment: If you are using the standard ajax navigation model, everything is in the same page, so yes.

Comment: I believe I am, but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Is there anything special I might need to do for things like flipswitches in dialog boxes?

Comment: You should post some code, and even create a jsFiddle so we can see what you are doing. The things you mention are jQM widgets which have their  own properties and methods. See the API documentation: http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/widgets/

Comment: As requested (and as I should have been done to begin with) @ezanker you will now find my code above

Comment: Try binding the click event from the parent form via event delegation: $(document).on('change','.sliderSelector', sliderClicked()); That way the sliders don't have to exist at the time you bind the function. After changing a slider value, call .slider( "refresh" ); on the slider.

Comment: After some testing, I found the solution. (.slider('refresh'); was definitely missing)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to move the function sliderClicked to the same file as the dialog page and change the javascript there to such:

```
$(document).delegate('#option-window', 'pageinit', function() {
    $('#sliderOne').val(sliderOneVal).slider("refresh");
    $('#sliderTwoOption').val(sliderTwoVal).slider("refresh");

    $('.sliderSelector').bind('change', sliderClicked);
});
```